# Provider: setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, flutter-hive

I'm using **Hive** to store the whole list of `Card` items, related to an `Extension`. In the screen of the selected extension, I am displaying the Cards of this extension, with bunch of filters/sorting.

To do that, I use `ValueListenableBuilder` to get the current extension and their cards.

And when I filter/sort this list, I want to store them into my `Provider` class, because I would to reuse this list into another screen.

But we I do `context.read<ShowingCardsProvider>().setAll(sortedList)`, I got this error:

```
setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
```

I don't listen `ShowingCardsProvider` anywhere for now.

Can you explain to me what's wrong here?

Thank you!

**main.dart**

```dart
  runApp(MultiProvider(
    providers: [
      ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: AuthProvider()),
      ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: UserProvider()),
      ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: ShowingCardsProvider()),
    ],
    child: MyApp(),
  ));
```

**showing_cards_provider.dart**

```
import 'dart:collection';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:pokecollect/card/models/card.dart';

class CardsProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  final List<CardModel> _items = [];

  UnmodifiableListView<CardModel> get items => UnmodifiableListView(_items);

  void setAll(List<CardModel>? items) {
    _items.clear();
    if (items != null || items!.isNotEmpty) {
      _items.addAll(items);
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void addAll(List<CardModel> items) {
    _items.addAll(items);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void removeAll() {
    _items.clear();
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

**extension_page.dart**

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
          return CustomScrollView(
            slivers: [
              SliverAppBar(
                ...
              ),
              ...
              SliverPadding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                sliver: ValueListenableBuilder(
                  valueListenable: ExtensionBox.box.listenable(keys: [_extensionUuid]),
                  builder: (ctx, Box<Extension> box, child) {
                    List<CardModel>? cardsList = box
                        .get(_uuid)!
                        .cards
                        ?.where((card) => _isCardPassFilters(card))
                        .cast<CardModel>()
                        .toList();

                    var sortedList = _simpleSortCards(cardsList);

                    context.read<ShowingCardsProvider>().setAll(sortedList);

                    return _buildCardListGrid(sortedList);
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ]
          );
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed because I'm using `ValueListenableBuilder` and, while the Widget is building, `notifyListeners` is called (into my provider).

My hotfix is to do this:

```dart
return Future.delayed(
  Duration(milliseconds: 1),
  () => context.read<ShowingCardsProvider>().setAll(list),
);
```

Not very beautiful, but it works

If you have a more elegant way, fell free to comment it!